# Does a vertical asymptote mean it is not a function?

Tags: functions, asymptotics, graphing-functions

I know that a function is defined as something where very input has a unique output, but does "undefined" or "infinity" count as a unique output?

In other words, would a reciprocal function count as a formally defined function? Or would it not because of the asymptote?

Comment: It would not be defined (as a *real* function) at the point of vertical asymptote. However, if you allow extended reals, or even functions on more exotic spaces like the Riemann sphere, then ... yes. I think. I mention those for completeness but I don’t know much about them

Comment: That said, $1/x$ is a well defined function on any real domain not including $0$. So, it’s not as simple as: “it is a function, it isn’t a function”

Comment: It is a function on its domain (which excludes the point where the asymptote is).

Comment: Let $f:\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=1/x$. Then, $f$ is a function, because by definition, $1/x$ means the *unique* number $y$ such that $xy=1$. Since the domain of $f$ does not contain $0$, it does not make sense to ask what $f(0)$ is. When we say $f(0)$ is undefined, this just means that $f$ is *not defined* at $0$; it does not mean that if we plug in $0$ to $f$, then some quantity "undefined" is returned. Finally, it is not the case that $1/0=\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

When defining a function, it is crucial to consider the set that we are inputting (the domain) and the set that we are outputting (the codomain).
The notion of "undefined" is not a unique output because it is not a point in any sort of codomain.
In certain special cases, we can define a specific output of a function to be infinity (or a point "at infinity"), but we do not regard a function as well defined if the function makes no sense for some point in the domain.

To answer your other question, let us just consider functions which input real numbers and output real numbers.
The reciprocal function is certainly a well defined function, but only in domains which do not include the point zero.
Around the asymptote, the function behaves nicely, and we can say it is well defined there because the points approaching the asymptote is the output of numbers approaching zero. It is only at the point zero where we have a problem.

So the answer to your question is that it can be both.
If zero is in our domain, then we do not have a well defined function.
If zero is not in our domain, then we have a well defined function.

Comment: This is a fine answer. (+1) Our OP has not been taught that to describe a function, it’s necessary to specify not only the rule but also the domain (and sometimes it’s worthwhile to mention the codomain (target space) as well). This is a defect of high-school teaching that I have been inveighing against for rather a while now.